# What is the ReadInfoFromVsixManifest task?

Tags: c#

I am getting this error while building a vsix project on VS 2019.

Error       The "PackagePaths" parameter is not supported by the "ReadInfoFromVsixManifest" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a gettable public instance property.

Does anyone have a clue what it means?  I can't find a thing when I Google it.

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem when building vsix. But it will be ok when I reboot Visual Studio.